# How do I create/use the equivalent of "Application Context" in an ASP .NET application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms

I have the task of migrating an old WinForms application to ASP .NET.

The WinForms application uses an "Application Context" class to store variables such as the user's name, a couple of tables of data for populating listboxes and the SQL Server Connection (and conenction string) - amongst other things.

What is the best way to globally refer to such shared properties and variables in the same/a similar way for just a period of being logged in after e.g. successful SQL Server authentication?

Thank you,

M.Young

Comment: Why on earth would you do such a thing? The performance is going to be nigh unbearable.

Comment: PS. You need to be clearer when describing "globally" when describing a "multi-user" environment. If we store the user's name globally on a multi-user environment you will have a very interesting bug...>_<

Comment: I think most people would have got the point of my question. I'm asking how to have a set of variables/values/objects which are used over and over again during a single user's session and in my WinForms app they are accessible via the application context.

My question is whether what the approach would be in ASP .NET to achieve the same for a single user and if performance would be "unbearable" feel free to suggest how you might otherwise do it.

Comment: The problem is that http is stateless. Given that... Webforms gets around this using `postback`. The result is the apps state is sent in each request. Each button press causes a request. The result is that each action on you app takes seconds. My advice, depends on why you are doing this... But most likely you should look at citric/terminal services remote app.

Comment: So my approach is presumably wrong and I can't start working with ASP .NET using the approach I had with WinForms.

I simply want a user to attempt to log in (using SQL Server authentication) and then for there to be certain information that I can just refer to within code elsewhere like a language preference or a skin name etc etc.

Where would one keep the connection string to an SQL Server database normally after a user has successfully logged in until they're finished with what they're doing?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to port would be to store those things in session. You can populate it by by:

```
session["thingsList"] = List<things> ...
```

And access it by:

```
var things = (List<things>) session["thingsList"]
```

Make sure to configure session timeout to match the authentication timeout.

Check out MSDN, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581%28v=vs.140%29.aspx, for more information.

Comment: Beware. Session is likely to cause issues for certain types of data, as browsers have tabs. This means each user can (will) open multiple instances of their application, which share the same session.